# Apply CSS to an element that belongs to two classes but not those two classes individually

Tags: html, css

Is it possible: I have a div that belongs to two classes and I want to add some more config to the div but dont want the parent classes individually to have those properties. E.g.

div-one

```
<div class="classA classB">Some Text</div>
```

div-two

```
<div class="classA"></div>
```

div-three

```
<div class="classB"></div>
```

Now in the CSS file:

```
.classA{
height:100%,
width:100%
}
classB{
text-align:center,
etc:etc
}
```

Now how do I apply some additional config to the div-one without adding those config options to the classes A & B and I cannot use the ID property because the div gets created dynamically. So I want some functionality like

```
.classA .classB{
//additional config
}
```

But I dont want the additional config to be applied to div-two and div-three

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to style only the `div` that has *both* `classA` and `classB` correct? If so, here is how you do that:

```
.classA.classB {
//additional config
}
```

Note how there is no space between the two classes. This means that the styles you set will only be applied to elements that have both `classA` and `classB`

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/NbJ2j/

Comment: What happens if I add the space, then will those get added to classA and classB config as well?

Comment: @user3457003 you must mark it as an answer, it solves your problem perfectly.

Comment: @user3457003 If you add a space, then it will style all `classB` elements that are *children* of `classA` elements. See here for more info on how CSS selectors work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Comment: this will also failed if one extra space added between classes.

Comment: @Bhavik I was trying to mark it as an answer but it said that I have to wait for a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

There is always several ways to target an element with CSS. 
In you case, you can for instance add a classC to the first div. Or select it with a pseudo selector:

```
div:first-of-type {color: blue;}
```

Comment: but you logic will fail. if the `div` sequence changed.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Not to mention OP mentioned that the `div`s are dynamically generated so there is very good chance that the order of the elements will change. Also, this only works if the elements in question are the first on the page. This will fail if they are within a parent `div`.

Comment: this is not a great solution because adding new elements will be difficult as per this logic. But still thanks for trying.